# My Regex for File Filter Attribute in NiFi GetFile Processor is Failing

Tags: apache-nifi

I have a list of files to copy to HDFS.

The File names are like:

1. Sample-11072016
2. Sample-11082016
3. Sample-11062016
4. Sample-11062016
5. Denodo-09082016
6. Denodo-09122016
7. Denodo-11082016
8. Denodo-11072016

Now I am trying to write a regex which would pick Today's *Sample* file.
The digits following the file are dates as in

> Sample-11082016 is the file of date 11/08/2016

The regex I tried is `[Sample]-(0-9){8}`
This regex would return all Sample files with of all dates as I am checking for 8 digits.
Could you please suggest on how to find the file with today's date.
The problem here is the File name *Sample* stays constant where as the date keeps changing.
I have to write a regex so that it would pick the file of today's date only.

I am pretty new to Regex, is it possible to write a regex to check if the date is today's date.

Any suggestions would help.
NIFI regex Rules are same as Java Regex rules.
The Regex Expression should be used against the `File Filter` Attribute of `GetFile` Processor

Regards,

Sai_PB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're almost there on the regex. By putting "Sample" in between the square brackets ('[' and ']'), you're saying "The first character should match one of these characters". Here is a [link](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-regex/syntax.html) that explains it a bit more in depth (see the "Character Classes" section).

Also by putting "0-9" in paranthesis, you're saying "Capture this group that matches the characters '0-9' exactly". Here is where you want the square brackets.

So the regex you should be using is "Sample-[0-9]{8}" (you can use "\d" instead of "0-9" but I wanted to keep as much of your initial regex as possible).

You can test your regex using this [website](http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html).

In order to solve the second problem of picking up the current day's log file, you should be able to use the above regex as the File Filter. Then adjust the "Scheduling Strategy" to run once a day (after the file is expected to be written for the day). Lastly set the "Maximum File Age" to "24h" (adjust as necessary to be sure only the latest is valid). These configurations will cause the processor to run once per day, picking up only a file that matches the appropriate filter and is not older than a day old.

Comment: Well the Regex '[Sample]-(0-9){8}' would select all the Sample irrespective of dates, But my requirement is to select files of the present day only. For that I can write '[Sample]-[Today's date]'. In this case I need to change the regex everyday, instead I am trying to find a way to automate this, like the  script should pick the files automatically without me changing the regex everyday.

Comment: Ah sorry I completely missed that part of your question. A couple follow up questions: do you want to continuously stream the files as they are created or once a day pick them all up? after you bring them into NiFi can they be deleted (GetFile property: Keep Source File)?

Comment: And you're not trying to "tail" a rolling file as another system writes to it? (you want to pick up the file after something has written to disk once)

Comment: It is a continuous stream of files, one new version of the file comes-in everyday, but I need to have a separate GetFile processor for each table. So the processor should pick only the current date's file from the pool of its older versions. I am trying to accomplish it by writing a RegEx in the FileFileter property of GetFile processor.

Comment: Rgr. just updated the answer to accomplish picking up the appropriate log once a day.

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same problem today and i am using List SFTP to take files from ftp server and putting them to HDFS.
I was able to put the file filter but adding today's date was not possible because List SFTP file filter does't support nifi expression language.
I made a solution at the source end to move the daily files once i will ready them to the another folder, so that i will always get new file in my source folder.
Also, you can go through the below thread where you can find some other work around of this issue.

http://apache-nifi.1125220.n5.nabble.com/How-to-get-ftp-file-according-to-Current-date-td16412.html

Regards
Nitin