# Regex pattern to pick latest file in nifi

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-nifi

I have a `NiFi` flow where I am getting all data from `s3` and putting it in the destination folder. Now, the requirement is if there is any latest data then just transfer the latest data only. I have a data file in `s3` like below:

```
20201130-011101493.parquet
20201129-011101493.parquet
```

And the regex I tried:

```
\d[0-9]{8}.parquet
```

The problem is it is not picking the first file which is the latest data i.e `30/11/2020`

How can I modify my regex so that it will be picking the latest file only if the job runs once per day? I also referred [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40486113/my-regex-for-file-filter-attribute-in-nifi-getfile-processor-is-failing) but I guess I am not able to get my regex correct.

Comment: are you using fetch3s to get data out of the bucket ?

Comment: currently, I am using lists3 and fetchs3object processors